# How to put dynamic link ignoring the domain on Javascript?

Tags: html

I am working with different environments, I have a DEV env, QA env, STG env and obviously PRODUCTION.

And I don't want to change the link everytime that there are going to tests on the different environments; so I have this:

```
<a name="submit_button"
   href="https://hl5.boa.com/hl5boa/confirmation.html">
   Submit
</a>
```

That one is the link for production. So before pushing the code to the different env I have to keep changing the link. If the link goes to dev env, I have to put:

```
<a name="submit_button"
   href="https://DEV-hl5.boa.com/hl5boa/confirmation.html">
   Submit
</a>
```

or to QA

```
<a name="submit_button"
   href="https://QA-hl5.boa.com/hl5boa/confirmation.html">
   Submit
</a>
```

So, what can I do to avoid doing that?

Comment: Rather than doing this client-side, if absolute URLs are required, exposing the sub-domain of your various environments to every client who visits your site, I'd strongly suggest running checks such as this either as an automated step in your production process or on the server when the page is accessed.

Comment: If you can use PHP you could hack away with the $_SERVER variable. Otherwise, i would suggest using relative links instead. EDIT: NVM, you can use "window.location.host" has alternative to $_SERVER (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a relative link:

```
<a name="submit_button"
   href="/hl5boa/confirmation.html">
   Submit
</a>
```

See [Absolute URLs vs relative URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs) and [Hyperlink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Hyperlink#In_depth)

You could also use a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element, but there's really no need.